# Why save the old base pointer at beginning of function?

Tags: function, assembly, stack

What's the point of saving the old base pointer on the stack at the beginning of a function? I'm new to working with functions in assembly, but so far I have yet to see the point of doing this. It just gets pushed onto the stack and then popped off at the end, it doesn't do anything. For example the following code works just fine without doing this:

```
.section .data
.section .text
.globl _start

.type add, @function
add:
    mov %rsp, %rbp
    mov 8(%rbp), %rax
    mov 16(%rbp), %rdi
    add %rax, %rdi

    mov %rbp, %rsp
    ret

_start:
    push $45
    push $36
    call add
    add  $16, %rsp

    mov $60, %rax
    syscall
```

I know that you could have simplified this even further by just using the stack pointer in this example, but I can see how that's bad practice.

Comment: It's so that you can call another function inside the function. (The base pointer points to the stack frame of the function).

Comment: +1 simple&basic but beautiful question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every function using `xBP` to locate its parameters or local variables needs to set `xBP` to `xSP` at the very beginning.

By doing so, it destroys the previous value of `xBP` from the calling function and so, naturally, it should save and restore it by e.g. using `push` and `pop`.

If `xBP` isn't used at all, it doesn't need to be saved and restored.

Many compilers have an option to use `xSP` to locate function parameters and local variables. If that option is enabled, `xBP` may not need to be preserved (unless the calling convention requires its preservation).